C# Azure.AI or Azure.Communication not working for 'ChatMessage', it could be deprecated
I followed this video here
github_link
 var cloudEvents = await context.Request.ReadFromJsonAsync<CloudEvent[]>() ?? Array.Empty<CloudEvent>();
    var contextId = context.Request.RouteValues["contextId"]?.ToString() ?? "";
    var callerId = context.Request.Query["callerId"].ToString() ?? "";

    foreach (var cloudEvent in cloudEvents)
    {
        // Parse the cloud event to get the call event details
        CallAutomationEventBase callEvent = CallAutomationEventParser.Parse(cloudEvent);
        var callConnection = callClient.GetCallConnection(callEvent.CallConnectionId);
        var callConnectionMedia = callConnection.GetCallMedia();

        var messages = chatSessions[contextId];

        var phoneId = new PhoneNumberIdentifier(callerId); 

        if (callEvent is CallConnected)
        {
            // If the call is connected, get a response from the chatbot and send it to the user
            var response = await GetChatGPTResponse(messages);
            messages.Add(new ChatMessage(ChatRole.Assistant, response));
            await SayAndRecognize(callConnectionMedia, phoneId, response);
        }
        if (callEvent is RecognizeCompleted recogEvent 
            && recogEvent.RecognizeResult is SpeechResult speech_result)
        {
            // If speech is recognized, get a response from the chatbot based on the recognized speech and send it to the user
            messages.Add(new ChatMessage(ChatRole.User, speech_result.Speech));
            
            var response = await GetChatGPTResponse(messages);
            messages.Add(new ChatMessage(ChatRole.Assistant, response));
            await SayAndRecognize(callConnectionMedia, phoneId, response);
        }                 
    } 


and have all the requirements set up for the app however it was last updated 7 months ago and the latest dependency versions mean that certain types are deprecated (I think) such as 'ChatMessage' or 'CognitiveServicesEndpoint'. There is, however, no documentation I can find to indicate what they have become.
I have tried installing other libraries and updating certain things but with nothing achieved I don't know what else to do.

please share the code you tried

@Sampath github link here is the specific c# code. The keywords ChatMessage along with others don't work

Change the pacakge
<PackageReference Include="Azure.Communication.CallAutomation" Version="1.2.0" /> 


and try with below code :
The code is taken from git. It integrates Azure services to build a sophisticated automated call system.

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);


var configuration = builder.Configuration;


var AZURE_COG_SERVICES_KEY = configuration["AZURE_COG_SERVICES_KEY"] ?? throw new Exception("AZURE_COG_SERVICES_KEY is not set");
var AZURE_COG_SERVICES_ENDPOINT = configuration["AZURE_COG_SERVICES_ENDPOINT"] ?? throw new Exception("AZURE_COG_SERVICES_ENDPOINT is not set");
var ACS_CONNECTION_STRING = configuration["ACS_CONNECTION_STRING"] ?? throw new Exception("ACS_CONNECTION_STRING is not set");
var ACS_PHONE_NUMBER = configuration["ACS_PHONE_NUMBER"] ?? throw new Exception("ACS_PHONE_NUMBER is not set");
var OPENAI_ENDPOINT = configuration["OPENAI_ENDPOINT"] ?? throw new Exception("OPENAI_ENDPOINT is not set");
var OPENAI_KEY = configuration["OPENAI_KEY"] ?? throw new Exception("OPENAI_KEY is not set");
var OPENAI_DEPLOYMENT_NAME = configuration["OPENAI_DEPLOYMENT_NAME"] ?? throw new Exception("OPENAI_DEPLOYMENT_NAME is not set");
var HOST_NAME = configuration["HOST_NAME"] ?? throw new Exception("HOST_NAME is not set");


var callClient = new CallAutomationClient(ACS_CONNECTION_STRING);

var chatSessions = new Dictionary<string, List<ChatMessage>>();


builder.Services.AddSingleton(callClient);
builder.Services.AddSingleton(chatSessions);

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseDefaultFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.MapPost("/api/generate_prompt", async context =>
{
   
    var file = context.Request.Form.Files[0];
    using var reader = new StreamReader(file.OpenReadStream());

  
    AzureKeyCredential credential = new AzureKeyCredential(AZURE_COG_SERVICES_KEY);
    DocumentAnalysisClient docClient = new DocumentAnalysisClient(new Uri(AZURE_COG_SERVICES_ENDPOINT), credential);

    
    AnalyzeDocumentOperation operation = await docClient.AnalyzeDocumentAsync(
        WaitUntil.Completed, "prebuilt-read", reader.BaseStream);
    AnalyzeResult result = operation.Value;

    t
    string prompt = @"You are a receptionist at a health clinic whose primary goal is to help me, 
    a patient, fill out their patient intake forms. You are friendly and concise. 
    For each question in the form ask me a question get the information, then wait for my answer. 
    For example, start 'What is you name?', then I will response 'John Smith',  
    then ask 'What is your date of birth?' and I will respond, 'Jan 4, 1999'.\n\nPATIENT INTAKE FORM:\n\n";

    prompt += result.Content;

   
    await context.Response.WriteAsync(prompt);
});

app.MapPost("/api/call", async context =>
{
    
    var data = await context.Request.ReadFromJsonAsync<CallRequest>();
    if (data == null) return;

    
    var callInvite = new CallInvite(
        new PhoneNumberIdentifier(data.PhoneNumber),
        new PhoneNumberIdentifier(ACS_PHONE_NUMBER)
    );

   
    var contextId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    var messages = new[] {
        new ChatMessage(ChatRole.System, data.Prompt)
    };
    
    chatSessions[contextId] = messages.ToList();

   
    var createCallOptions = new CreateCallOptions(callInvite,
        new Uri($"{HOST_NAME}/api/callbacks/{contextId}?callerId={WebUtility.UrlEncode(data.PhoneNumber)}"));

   
    var result = await callClient.CreateCallAsync(createCallOptions);
});

app.MapPost("/api/callbacks/{contextId}", async (context) =>
{
    
    var cloudEvents = await context.Request.ReadFromJsonAsync<CloudEvent[]>() ?? Array.Empty<CloudEvent>();
    var contextId = context.Request.RouteValues["contextId"]?.ToString() ?? "";
    var callerId = context.Request.Query["callerId"].ToString() ?? "";

    foreach (var cloudEvent in cloudEvents)
    {
        
        CallAutomationEventBase callEvent = CallAutomationEventParser.Parse(cloudEvent);
        var callConnection = callClient.GetCallConnection(callEvent.CallConnectionId);
        var callConnectionMedia = callConnection.GetCallMedia();

        var messages = chatSessions[contextId];

        var phoneId = new PhoneNumberIdentifier(callerId);

        if (callEvent is CallConnected)
        {
          
            var response = await GetChatGPTResponse(messages);
            messages.Add(new ChatMessage(ChatRole.Assistant, response));
            await SayAndRecognize(callConnectionMedia, phoneId, response);
        }
        if (callEvent is RecognizeCompleted recogEvent
            && recogEvent.RecognizeResult is SpeechResult speech_result)
        {
          
            messages.Add(new ChatMessage(ChatRole.User, speech_result.Speech));

            var response = await GetChatGPTResponse(messages);
            messages.Add(new ChatMessage(ChatRole.Assistant, response));
            await SayAndRecognize(callConnectionMedia, phoneId, response);
        }
    }
});

app.Run();


async Task<string> GetChatGPTResponse(List<ChatMessage> messages)
{
  
    OpenAIClient openAIClient = new OpenAIClient(
        new Uri(OPENAI_ENDPOINT),
        new AzureKeyCredential(OPENAI_KEY));

    
    var openAIMessages = messages.Select(m => new Azure.AI.OpenAI.ChatMessage(m.Role, m.Content)).ToList();

   
    var chatCompletionsOptions = new ChatCompletionsOptions(openAIMessages);
    Response<ChatCompletions> response = await openAIClient.GetChatCompletionsAsync(
        deploymentOrModelName: OPENAI_DEPLOYMENT_NAME,
        chatCompletionsOptions);

    return response.Value.Choices[0].Message.Content;
}


async Task SayAndRecognize(CallMedia callConnectionMedia, PhoneNumberIdentifier phoneId, string response)
{
  
    var chatGPTResponseSource = new TextSource(response)
    {
        VoiceName = "en-US-JennyMultilingualV2Neural"
    };

    
    var recognizeOptions =
        new CallMediaRecognizeSpeechOptions(
            targetParticipant: CommunicationIdentifier.FromRawId(phoneId.RawId))
        {
            Prompt = chatGPTResponseSource,
            EndSilenceTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500)
        };

    var recognize_result = await callConnectionMedia.StartRecognizingAsync(recognizeOptions);
}

public class CallRequest
{
    public required string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public required string Prompt { get; set; }
}

public class ChatMessage
{
    public string Role { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public ChatMessage(string role, string content)
    {
        Role = role;
        Content = content;
    }
}

public static class ChatRole
{
    public const string System = "system";
    public const string Assistant = "assistant";
    public const string User = "user";
}



Output: A prompt for the chatbot that includes the contents of the patient intake form.

Example Output:
You are a receptionist at a health clinic whose primary goal is to help me, 
a patient, fill out their patient intake forms. You are friendly and concise. 
For each question in the form ask me a question get the information, then wait for my answer. 
For example, start 'What is you name?', then I will response 'John Smith',  
then ask 'What is your date of birth?' and I will respond, 'Jan 4, 1999'.

PATIENT INTAKE FORM:

[Content of the uploaded form]



